# display comments on different categories

Tags: wordpress

I want to only display comments on one of the categories on my wordpress site. So for example my pear category with posts on it will have a comment function available but on my orange page the comment section will be disabled.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the `content.php` file change:

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
<div class="comments-link">
    <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .comments-link -->
<?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
```

to

```
<?php
$postid = get_the_ID();
$category = get_the_category( $postid );
$category = $category[0]->cat_name;
if ($category == "Pear") 
{
    if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
        <div class="comments-link">
        <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .comments-link -->
    <?php endif; // comments_open() 
} 
?>
```

and in the `comments.php` file change:

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
```

to

```
<?php 
    $postid = get_the_ID();
$category = get_the_category( $postid );
$category = $category[0]->cat_name;
if ($category == "Pear") 
    {
        if ( have_comments() ) : 
?>
```

**AND** change:

```
<?php endif; // have_comments() ?>
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

to

```
<?php endif; // have_comments() ?>
<?php comment_form(); 
}
?>
```

The above should only display comments in posts that are in the `Pear` category.